# Why are these requests in my Apache logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, log-files

I've found the following lines in my Apache 2.2 logs (using the standard "combined" log format):

```
92.240.68.152 - - [10/Feb/2013:20:47:38 +0000] "GET http://8stepschools.com/images/8stances_tiger.jpg HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "webcollage/1.135a"
94.75.247.144 - - [10/Feb/2013:11:09:35 +0000] "HEAD http://www.lenta.ru/info/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ( Windows; U; Windows NT4.0; FireFox )"
```

I've never heard of these sites. We certainly don't link or redirect to them. These don't seem like remote clients probing for a proxy - from what I gathered proxy requests end up with a 200 or a 404

**What are these requests and why is my server redirecting to them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be attempts to see if your server works as a proxy. The number after the request is just the status code returned by your server. 200 being OK and 404 being page not found. A 30X response indicates that your website is configured to redirect all requests for non-existent URIs (which these will be) to another page/website.

If you've only get a couple, I wouldn't bother worrying about them.

Comment: let me check that... which apache directive is responsible for handling requests for non-existent URIs?

Comment: Could be a Redirect or RewriteRule. Quite possibly in a .htaccess file. Lots of web apps are configured by default to redirect all URIs that don't map to a real path/file.